# Using GraalVM to run Java on Heroku

Tags: java, performance, heroku, cold-start

Is there any ability to use GraalVM to run Java apps on Heroku? I read a lot articles about cold starts of Java applications with GraalVM AOT (ahead-of-time) compilation feature and how it decrease startup time and I'd like to try to use it in my projects deployed on Heroku.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This buildpack](https://github.com/jkutner/graal-buildpack) can be used with the Heroku Java buildpack to replace the default JDK with Graal by running:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/jkutner/graal-buildpack
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/java
```

Comment: Will there be official support for GraamVM in the future? The mentioned buildpack is outdated.

Comment: @codefinger, are you planning an updated version. I couldn't get this one to run.